# W3C validation error

Tags: html, validation

The line

```
<a class="product_image" href="http://www.symposiumwines.com/shop/product.php?id_product=11" >
<img class="f-p"src="/shop/img/p/11-53-home.jpg" height="115" width="115" alt="Saint-Aubin 1er Cru &#039;Les Frionnes&#039; 2004"/>
</a>
```

generated by a CMS throws a couple of errors when I validate the page.

1) Attributes construct error

2) Couldn't find end of Start Tag img line

indicating the "p" of "php" in both cases.

It does validate using the Firefox plug-in, it does not validate in the W3C validator online.

Any suggestion? I am baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this fragment to validate as XHTML you must insert a space between `class="f-p"` and `src="`

Answer (score 0):

Are you pasting your php code into the validator? If so, your firefox plugin will validate because it's parsing the html, but the w3c validator will fail because it won't parse php.

The best way to test this is to click "view source" in your browser, copy paste that html to the w3c validator and see if that validates.

If it does, everything is fine.