# Using the <img> element in XHTML

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm a noob and learning HTML to begin with.
I used the following code and tried to validate it at [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/).

```
<p><img src="C:\Users\46506090\Pictures\FS Capture\2015-08-28_103100.png" alt="stay calm" width="100" height="80" /></p>
```

I'm getting the following error during validation.
[image]

*I don't understand what needs to be done to fix this*. The `Clean up Markup with HTML-Tidy` option in this validator page adds the following code to make it clean.

```
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
```

Comment: Add a space after `"` will fix.

Comment: can you be more specific? Just tell me after which word

Comment: possible duplicate of [W3C validation error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982681/w3c-validation-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is caused by (looks like) not having a space between the closing <strike>parenthesis</strike> quotation mark and the next parameter name, but it looks like it's fixed in your initial example, just not in the screenshots.